# Replace text between two strings

Tags: regex, stata

I have a list of addresses that are generally of the following type:

> 1000 Currie AV  Apt:   Minneapolis MN 55403
>
> 1843 Polk ST NE Apt:  b
>
> 1801 3 AV S Apt:  203 Minneapolis MN 55404
>
> 2900 Thomas AV S Apt:  1618 MPLS MN 55416
>
> 8409 Elliott AV S Apt:   Bloomington MN 55420

I am new to regular expressions.

I would like to replace `Apt:` and all the text until the first capital letter with a blank.

Right now the code that I am trying is the following:

```
generate address_home = regexr(address_home1, "(Apt:).*?([A-Z])", " ")
```

Comment: Which language are you running?

Comment: Nothing needs to be fixed, just repace with the space between the capture groups. `$1<space>$2` or `\1<space>\2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex:**

```
Apt:[^A-Z\n]*
```

Replace the matched characters with a single space.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rX5eE5/1)

I think your code would be,

```
gen address_home = regexr(address_home1, "Apt:[^A-Z\n]*", " ")
```

**OR**

```
gen address_home = regexr(address_home1, "Apt:[^A-Z\\n]*", " ")
```

<sub>Don't know whether you need to escape the backslash one more time or not</sub>.

Comment: Thanks so much!  This worked.  I am not sure why the regex above did not work.  I tried the code suggested and it did not work.  This formulation however did.  Thanks again!

Comment: @WCB [accept if this works.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) Some languages won't support lookahead or lookebhinds but most of the languages would support negated character class `[^...]`

Answer (score 1):

A **regular expression** is always useful to know but here the OP may not always need it. In this *particular* case, a combination of the functions `strpos()` and `substr()` will mostly do the trick.

For example:

```
. clear 

input str50 adr
"1000 Currie AV Apt: Minneapolis MN 55403"
"1843 Polk ST NE Apt: b"
"1801 3 AV S Apt: 203 Minneapolis MN 55404"
"2900 Thomas AV S Apt: 1618 MPLS MN 55416"
"8409 Elliott AV S Apt: Bloomington MN 55420"
end


. generate adr2 =  substr(adr, 1, strpos(adr, ":") - 5) + ///
                   substr(adr, strpos(adr, ":") + 1, .)

. list

   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
   |                                         adr                                     adr2 |
   |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
1. |    1000 Currie AV Apt: Minneapolis MN 55403      1000 Currie AV Minneapolis MN 55403 |
2. |                      1843 Polk ST NE Apt: b                        1843 Polk ST NE b |
3. |   1801 3 AV S Apt: 203 Minneapolis MN 55404     1801 3 AV S 203 Minneapolis MN 55404 |
4. |    2900 Thomas AV S Apt: 1618 MPLS MN 55416      2900 Thomas AV S 1618 MPLS MN 55416 |
5. | 8409 Elliott AV S Apt: Bloomington MN 55420   8409 Elliott AV S Bloomington MN 55420 |
   +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The idea is to use the `:` as a reference point in order to eliminate the sub-string `Apt:` from each address, since its length is always constant.

---

**EDIT:**

@Nick Cox provides a similar but even more succinct solution:

```
generate adr3 = subinstr(adr, "Apt: ", "", .)
```

This simply replaces all instances of `Apt:` with `""`.

Comment: `subinstr(adr, "Apt: ", "", .)` removes `Apt: `.

Comment: Yes, very nice! I have incorporated this in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this (substitution) :

```
s/Apt:.*?(?=[A-Z])//g
```

This is usable with languages using perl or pcre regex.

- `s///` is the basic substitution skeleton
- `Apt:` litteral...
- `.*?` anything (non greedy)...
- `(?=[A-Z])` *look-around* regex technique to match an UPPER character but excluded from the match

Comment: Care to explain your solution a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex should be something like this:

```
.*(Apt:.*?)([A-Z]).*
```

And your code like this:

```
regexr(address_home1, ".*(Apt:.*?)([A-Z]).*", " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Stata's regex is [not very sophisticated](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/regular-expressions/) and I'm no regex expert, but this gets you close:

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data set -----

input ///
str30 adr
"1000 Currie AV Apt: Minneapolis MN 55403"
"1843 Polk ST NE Apt: b"
"1801 3 AV S Apt: 203 Minneapolis MN 55404"
"2900 Thomas AV S Apt: 1618 MPLS MN 55416"
"8409 Elliott AV S Apt: Bloomington MN 55420"
end

list

*----- what you want -----

gen adr2 = itrim(regexr(adr, "(Apt: *)([a-z0-9]*)", ""))

list
```

Resulting in:

```
. list

     +------------------------------------------------------------+
     |                            adr                        adr2 |
     |------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 1000 Currie AV Apt: Minneapoli   1000 Currie AV Minneapoli |
  2. |         1843 Polk ST NE Apt: b            1843 Polk ST NE  |
  3. | 1801 3 AV S Apt: 203 Minneapol       1801 3 AV S Minneapol |
  4. | 2900 Thomas AV S Apt: 1618 MPL        2900 Thomas AV S MPL |
  5. | 8409 Elliott AV S Apt: Bloomin   8409 Elliott AV S Bloomin |
     +------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If needed, you can use further string functions like `trim()`. See `help string functions`.